# Ubuntu - mounting partitions as read only

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

I have a server which has probably been shut down one time too many as a result of power cuts.  Now when I log in, it's mounted every partition I can see as read only.

I've looked up the solution, which is to get the machine to run a file system check on boot, but my problem is, because everything is read only, I can't edit anything!

How do I use `sudo touch /forcefsck` if I can't write anything?  Any tips?

Comment: `mount -o remount,rw` maybe. But that doesn't solve your underlying problems.

Comment: Well it would help if I could temporarily mount as RW, just so I could apply the other fix.  So looking at the options, that's:

mount (mount command) -O (as in the fstab) remount,rw (remount as read/write).

Doesn't appear to do anything though.

Comment: wait, I got it:

sudo mount -O remount,rw -force /dev/sda1 /

But it didn't work :(

Comment: ` sudo mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: "it didn't work" is insufficient information. What happened? What error message, if any, did you get?

Comment: And you could run `fsck` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

check the boot log => it has probably failed an auto fsck

Re-run the checks, fix the errors, and then it should cleanly boot/mount the drives next reboot.

try a live cd of your distrobution or something like http://www.sysresccd.org/

That should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same problem and after doing all possible checks and try-outs unsuccessfully I changed the sata cable and change to the next port to plug it in, and that did it, giving me along a huge improvement in performance